# Three.js Repeat texture fail

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, repeat, texture-wrapping

I'm trying to make a simple floor texture, but it seems that wrapS and wrapT don't works.

Look at the result: http://hpics.li/321350c

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "Game/Texture/drytext.png" );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 10, 10);
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(floor);
```

Thank you

Comment: Is the texture power of 2? (32x32, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, ...)

Comment: My fault, it was 255x255, need to sleep i think. Thank you

Comment: @mrdoob Why would that be required for wrapping the coordinates? It should be only necessary for mipmapping...

Comment: I don't know, I didn't design WebGL :)